# .htaccess remove RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following .htaccess code is used at my /business/ website, and as it is a demonstration website I would have to copy it several times, with different folder names... Like `/business/` `/restaurants/` `/law/`, etc

Is it possible to remove the `RewriteBase /business/` and `RewriteRule . /business/index.php [L]`?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /business/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /business/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you *should* just be able to do this, removing the `RewriteBase` and the absolute URI-path in the rule's target:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

But depending on the `index.php` and how it extracts URI info, it may not like it. You should be able to put that in any folder.